# Правильно ли писать команда из Крымска, или лучше: команда из города Крымск?

Tags: стилистика

Правильно ли писать: команда из Крымска, или  лучше: команда из города Крымск?

Answer (score 2):

Можно: КОМАНДА ИЗ КРЫМСКА, КОМАНДА ИЗ ГОРОДА КРЫМСКА. Второй вариант более официальный.